# compelling wchar_t to be 4 bytes

Tags: c, utf-8, utf, wchar-t

Practical question - I'm working on a little piece of app which runs on 2 separate hardware platforms.

The compilation method and it's configuration is defined and controlled by me.

My app receives a UTF-8/ISO-8859 text , and should perform some basic manipulation on the string (copying, searching etc).

Thing is, one compiler is GCC (sizeof(wchar_t) == 4) and the other is Mingw(sizeof(wchar_t) == 2).

In order to support all UTF-8 possibilities, I was thinking of "typedef"in wchar_t in my code to be of type uint32_t, so that will force the Mingw compiler to be on the same line, and covering all UTF-8 options.

I'm then planning to use the wide-char manipulation functions as provided by the standard library (mbstowcs, wcscmp, wcscpy, ex..)

Question is, will "forcing" the compiler to use more room, could have some bad impact (besides performance) on the library functioning (will mbtowcs even work here after the change? )

I tried using ICU, but it is a very large library and thus breaks the deal. i need it small and reliable .

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You say utf-8, but utf-8 uses `char`, not `wchar_t`.

Comment: That won't work. And it's not a compiler thing, it's a platform thing. Remember that mingw is gcc. And on Windows wchar_t is 2 bytes. End of story. If you need to work with UTF-32 data, use an appropriately sized element type. And then you talk about UTF-8. I think you need to back up.

Comment: The `wchar_t` type is useless except for Win32 interoperability.  Don't use it.  It is generally a mistake to use it on OS X or Windows.

Comment: @sashoalm UTF-16 is guaranteed to be 16 bits or less, UTF-8 can take up to 32 bits, it's a variable-width encoding.

Comment: @OP: Windows mistakenly interprets unicode text as UTF-16 formatted, so all unicode characters are of UTF-16 encoding and `wchar_t` is 16 bits long. UTF-8 supports every unicode character there is, and can take from 1 byte to 4 bytes. So, GCC defines `wchar_t` has having 4 bytes to support this correct implementation of unicode.

Comment: Conclusion: Use types that are ***at least 32 bits long***, like `unsigned int` on 32-bit systems

Comment: @APerson: UTF-16 also supports every character, but a single `wchar_t` cannot represent every code point.

Comment: @DietrichEpp UTF-16 doesn't support every unicode character. U+24B62 is the codepoint for ``, and its hex value is 0xF0A4ADA2.

Comment: @A: UTF-16 *does* support every Unicode character. Some characters will require surrogate pairs though. You're probably thinking of UCS-2.

Comment: @APerson: You are thinking of UCS-2.  UTF-16 supports all Unicode characters from U+0000 through U+10FFFF.  There aren't any other characters.

Comment: Edited my comment, if you can't display ****, which has a hex value of 0xF0A4ADA2, you can't claim to support UTF-8. The OP has explicitly mentioned UTF-8, not UTF-16.

Comment: @BillyONeal The euro sign in unicode, `€` has a hex value of 0xE282AC. Will that fit in a 16-bit type?

Comment: @APerson: The code point U+24B62 is encoded in UTF-16 as D852 DF62.  **UCS-2 and UTF-16 are different, and UTF-16 can represent all Unicode code points.**

Comment: @APerson: It is incorrect to state that `€` has a "hex value" of 0xE282AC.  It is encoded in UTF-8 as the sequence E2 82 AC, and it is encoded in UTF-16 as 20AC.  Its *value* is U+20AC.  Since its value fits in 16 bits, it is encoded as a single UTF-16 code unit.

Comment: @DietrichEpp The OP didn't mention UTF-16 at all, and is aiming to support UTF-8. UTF-16 is able to use up to 2 16-bit code units, but for the most part only 1 code unit is used per code point.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45398/discussion-between-dietrich-epp-and-a-person)

Comment: Have this mess with JNI; when once you think you got it portable, some honk comes around the corner with his world-saving invention.

Answer (score 6):

Here are your options for string manipulation:

1. Use `unsigned char` (or `char`) and UTF-8.  All the regular string manipulation functions work (like `strlen()`, `strstr()`, `snprintf()`, etc.).
2. Use `wchar_t` and use a different encoding on different platforms (Win32 uses UTF-16, OS X and Linux use UTF-32).  This is a path of madness, since you have to support two different encodings in the same code base.
3. Use UTF-32 or UTF-16 and your own string manipulation functions.  This is a lot of work, but it is portable.
4. Use ICU and UTF-16.

For most purposes, manipulating strings in UTF-8 works very well.  It depends on what your program does.  If you are doing things like parsing and templating, UTF-8 is easy to work with.  If you need more sophisticated functionality, such as iterating over break points or finding grapheme cluster boundaries, then you will need a library like Glib (which uses UTF-8) or ICU (which uses UTF-16).

### A note about indexes

You may be used to indexing strings using character / code point indexes.  Get used to indexing strings using code unit indexes: so `strlen()` returns the number of *bytes,* not the number of *characters.*  However, it is very rare to actually need to index a string by character position.

Comment: So if I have a wchar_t string and I want to erase from index 100 to index 105 I have to walk trough the array, since any encoded character might be 8 or 16 bits? Or is one element of wchar_t guaranteed( intended ) to hold only one character?

Comment: I read around a lot( never deal with unicode before ) and if I'm correct, wchat_t, which is 16 bits on windows, will hold only one character in one element. On linux it is 32 bits and one element will still hold only one character. Is this the point of utf-16, utf-32?

Comment: @2501: What you read is wrong.  On Windows, `wchar_t` will either hold one character or half of a character, because sometimes characters will be spread over two adjacent `wchar_t`.  This is why `wchar_t` is worthless and should be avoided, except when making Windows API calls.